# single button UIMenuController

Tags: iphone, ios, uimenucontroller

Good morning !

I'm writing an app which displays an outlet list, every outlet can sell 2 kind of product and / or can be an online shop.

For show this on my app I have added some "icons", but in case of they are bot enough "self explanatory" I'm looking for an easy-to-use way to explain.

So right know I'm using an `UImenuController` when the user tap on the icon (which is an `UIButton`)

I'm just looking for something simple, like the picture below :

[image]

But instead of the

> Highlight

I just want to put something like

> Sell x product

The problem I'm facing is that I can display this UIMenuController, but he has many many "garbages values" as you can see in this picture :

[image]

Not really cool right?

He is the method linked to my button :

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender event:(UIEvent*)event{

    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    UIView *buttonView=[[event.allTouches anyObject] view];
    CGRect buttonFrame=[buttonView convertRect:buttonView.frame toView:self.view];

    UIMenuItem *flag = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select" action:@selector(selectItem:)];

    UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

    [menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flag, nil]];

    [menu setTargetRect:buttonFrame inView:self.view];

    [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
}
```

I have obviously :

✔ Returned YES for 
`-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder`

✔ Returned YES for 
`-(BOOL)canPerformAction`

✔ Returned YES for 
`-(BOOL)canPerformAction`

✔ Returned YES for 
`-(BOOL)canPerformAction  -(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action` withSender:(id)sender

✔ The text "`Select`" does appear, but at the "end" of the menu (you must use the arrows to the right)

Any help and / or clue are welcome ! :-)

Comment: Tried with this tutorial http://www.g8production.com/post/19777758071/how-to-create-and-use-a-custom-uimenucontroller, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally managed (after spending the afternoon on Google & Stackoverflow) to achieve it !

It's easy : when you overwrite

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction -(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action
```

Just return

```
[super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
```

instead of

```
YES
```

and "voilà !"

:)